How to remove text from video
I tried many techniques and ai tools to remove text from my video but I still can't get desired results so can anyone help me
*Text is at centre so can't crop it

How did the text get into your video?

The centre of your video is usually the most important part of your image. Any attempt to 'fix' it is going to be more noticeable than fixing something near the edges.
I would try Content Aware Fill in After Effects - mask the text, expand and feather the mask slightly, make a 'clean plate' as much as you can, then use this to repair the shot.
One of the AI tools like Runway may get closer, but you're still going to be recreating lost information - nothing is likely to look perfect. If you can add a still or clip of the video to the question, you're likely to get a better answer.
